# How can I get android source code for 2.3 Calculator?

Tags: git, android-source

I thought following statement would get me current version of calculator at least from version 2.3.

```
git clone https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Calculator
```

But I was wrong. It's one of earlier versions. Does anybody know where I can find source code of Calculator for 2.3?

**UPDATE**: As comments below show, the source above are up-to-date version. I am sorry for the confusion but in my defense, I didn't think the app in my device was from third party because I manually upgraded the device to 2.3.

Comment: What leads you to believe that version is old?  All the tags on the latest commits in that repository elude to the fact that it is the 2.3 release, plus the gingerbread and gingerbread-release branch pointers match this master branch.

Comment: @Devunwired Good question. Main reason I thought that way was because the core calculator app on my 2.3 device was not the one in the source code. Looks similar but has better UI look. And I still think so.

Comment: But your question made me think the new version may be from Samsung or 3rd party provider...

Comment: The version on your device is very likely a custom app provided by the  OEM, especially if your device is running HTC Sense, Samsung Touchwiz, Motorola BLUR, etc.  They almost always provide proprietary versions of the core apps without releasing their own source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this:

http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android-apps/2.3_r1/com/android/calculator2/Calculator.java/

May be this is what you are looking for.

Comment: Thank you. That's exactly what I wanted. It turned out that the version is the same version I had and that I was wrong again. The new version I saw must be from third party provider.